# Why is lcov including system header files in my coverage report?

Tags: c++, g++, code-coverage, lcov

I'm generating a line/branch coverage report for a simple c++ app. I expect only one file, test.cpp, to be including in the report, but lcov adds about two dozen system header files to the coverage report. Here are just a few of the header files.

```
8/bits/stl_pair.h
8/bits/stl_tree.h
8/bits/stl_vector.h
8/bits/basic_string.h
8/bits.move.h
...
```

Does anyone know how to prevent these files from being included in the lcov coverage report?